# Floatrow package causing missing algorithm lines

Tags: floats, algorithms, floatrow

Hi I started using floatrow and noticed that it is breaking functionality of my algorithm code, both the algorithm header and footer have disappeared.  Here is a picture of before and after: [image]

Here are the packages I am using:

```
\usepackage[rawfloats=true]{floatrow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

And code from my algorithm block:

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{$P$}{$e$, $e'$, $t$, $T$}
    \If{$e' < e$}
        \Return 1.0 
    \Else
        \State\Return $exp^{-4.6 * {(e' / e)}^2 * ((T - t) / T)}$
    \EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Simulated Annealing}
\end{algorithm}
```

Any suggestions for a fix are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this is exactly what you want to do `{exp^{-4.6 * {(e' / e)}^2 * ((T - t) / T)}}`. If I were in yur shoes I would do `\exp{-4.6 * {(e' / e)}^2 * ((T - t) / T)}` or `e^{-4.6 * {(e' / e)}^2 * ((T - t) / T)}`.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the `rawfloats=true` option for `floatrow`; you can use `\RawFloats` either locally (inside some specific floating environment(s)) or in the form `\RawFloats[<type>]` in the preamble of your document for all floats of the given `<type>`. Here's an example showing the expected behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Function{$P$}{$e$, $e'$, $t$, $T$}
    \If{$e' < e$}
        \Return 1.0 
    \Else
        \State\Return $exp^{-4.6 * {(e' / e)}^2 * ((T - t) / T)}$
    \EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Simulated Annealing}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just inversed tho order of import I don't really know why and how but it works like magic haha

> `\usepackage{floatrow} 
>   \usepackage{algorithm}
>    \usepackage{algorithmic}`