# Floatrow distorts algorithm caption

Tags: floats, captions, algorithms, algorithmic, floatrow

This is the template for a conference: https://media.icml.cc/Conferences/ICML2020/Styles/icml2020_style.zip. I'm using that template for my paper. However, when I do `\usepackage{floatrow}`, it distorts the caption on my algorithm whose style is defined by the given `algorithm.sty` and `algorithmic.sty` files. How can I fix this? I've explored locally disabling the floatrow package but couldn't find any solution.

Some sample code:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{algorithm}[tb]
\caption{Some caption}
\label{alg:1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE some random algorithm
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I've tried the suggestion from here ([Floatrow package causing missing algorithm lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73240/floatrow-package-causing-missing-algorithm-lines)) but it doesn't work since I'm not using the `rawfloats=true` option anyway. It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: Plan B: Generate a standalone algorithm (separate pdf for example) and include it as a graphic.